# how to override method update in Django form?

Tags: django, django-orm

i have model like that :

```
class BrokerCredential(models.Model):
    api_key = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.api_key = self.api_key * 3
    super(BrokerCredential, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I override method 'save()' because I wanted every time and everywhere when I need to save record, this method manipulates my input.

But there is a problem, whenever I update my model ( consider changing the 'age' field), it multiples 'api_key' again.

I need a way that saves method works only when I add a new record, not every time I update my model instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change `api_key` only when the instance is created you can check whether the instance has a primary key yet or not:

```py
class BrokerCredential(models.Model):
    api_key = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None: # The instance is being created
            self.api_key = self.api_key * 3
        super(BrokerCredential, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

> **Note**: Although what you appear to do can be easily done in the forms or in the view and this method is not very reliable. For
> instance the method `bulk_create` does not call `save`.